# Avoid redundancy by @Path and @PathParam/@BeanParam in CXF

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I have some REST endpoints that are currently looking like this:

```
@Path("/{type}/{name}/doSomething")
public void doSomething(@PathParm("type") final String type, @PathParm("name") final String name);
```

You can already notice the redundancy by specifying the parameters in the `@Path` annotation on the method level and again in the `@PathParam` annotation on the parameter level.

As both `type` and `name` always come together and are used for multiple endpoints I want to aggregate them in a `@BeanParam` java bean. But this makes the the relationship between `@Path` and the parameters inside the bean even harder to spot as the `@PathParam` annotations would move to the bean class:

```
@Path("/{type}/{name}/doSomething")
public void doSomething(@BeanParam final TypeAndName typeAndName);
```

With this java bean class:

```
public class TypeAndName {

  @PathParam("type")
  private String type;

  @PathParam("name")
  private String name;

  // getters, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

A first step might be to create constants for the two parameters and use them in both places to improve readability but this doesn't solve the redundancy problem.

Is there any way to specify the path elements that correspond to the members of the bean in the bean itself to avoid this redundancy? Or is there any other/better approach to use keep both values together?

Comment: Personnaly i like the plain old way, `@Path` + `@PathParam` in the controller. It's a bit overwhelmed, but it's simplier and much more readable, and you don't have to open another class to actually see what you are referring to.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I share your opinion on this. However using a bean parameter would enable me to avoid endless repetition of the same java docs, the same swagger annotations, etc. I'm not talking about a small number of endpoints but likely around 100 or more.

Comment: Well, maybe you can add the `@Path("/{type}/{name}")` on the controller class  itself (if your framework allow you to do so) to specify that all uri inside will be prefixed with these params and then declare endpoint like so : `@Path("/doSomething") public void doSomething(@BeanParam final TypeAndName typeAndName);` But it sounds like code obfuscation to me ^^

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond There are actually dozens of controllers using theses parameters...

Comment: A super annotation then